# TypeError: Object of type Cart is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, python-3.x, session

I just started using session in Django framework. I have create an object cart from Cart model. And when i wan to set cart inside request.session with session['cart'] = cart, I get this error message: TypeError: Object of type Cart is not JSON serializable

This is my Cart model

```py
class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def addItem(self, itemCart):
        try:
            # get index of itemCart if exist
            index = self.items.index(itemCart)
            # itemCart exist then set its quantity
            self.items[index].setQuantity(
                self.items[index].quantity + itemCart.quantity)
        except ValueError:
            # the item does not exits then add to items list
            self.items.append(itemCart)
```

This is my view when i update the session

```py
cart = Cart()
session['cart'] = cart
```

And When i run the code i get this error:
 File "C:\Users\Patrick-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '
TypeError: Object of type Cart is not JSON serializable.

Please help

Comment: The `Cart` object would need to be serialized correctly (JSON or pickle if specified in settings.py) to make it possible to be stored in a session. A session cannot take a python instance, it would need serialization/deserialization steps in between. Consider adding `.dump` and `.load` methods for your `Cart` class, and use these methods to exchange the object shape between the states.

Answer (score 2):

If `Cart` is a model, you'll want to inherit from `models.Model`. That said, you can try:

```
from django.core import serializers
session['cart'] = serializers.serialize('json', Cart.objects.all())
```

Comment: The `Cart` is not a django model as shown above. You can't do `.objects` on it.

Comment: Which is why I prefaced my answer with "if Cart is a model". It wasn't clear to me if it was a transcription error or they had mistakenly forgot to derive from `models.Model`.

Comment: A `Cart` instance would need to contain a arbitrary number of `Item` objects, which would involve two more steps of interaction levels between the two, and these would have to be implemented to be used towards the end with the approach you suggested.